# How to generate this kind of multidimensional array from given tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have 2 tables ( tor_user_table , skill )

table name : tor_user_table:

```
  ->top_user_id(primary)
  ->top_zilla
  ->top_division
  ->f_name
  ->l_name
  ->top_description
   more....
```

table name: skill

```
  -> skill_id(int)
  -> top_user_id(int)
  -> skill_name(int)
```

I want to get a multidimensional array like this

```
$result = array(
    "0" => array(
        "tor_user_table" => array(
            "top_user_id"     => "13",
            "top_zilla"       => "10",
            "top_division"    => "1",
            "top_description" => "something written",
            "f_name"          => "Aniruddha",
            "l_name"          => "Chakraborty"
        ), // end of tor_user_table array for [0]
        "skill" => array(
            "0" => array(
                "skill_id"    => "13",
                "top_user_id" => "13",
                "skill_name"  => "1"
            ),
            "1" => array(
                "skill_id"    => "14",
                "top_user_id" => "13",
                "skill_name"  => "2"
            )
        ) // end of skill table for [0]
    ), // end of [0]

    "1" => array(
        "tor_user_table" => array(
            "top_user_id"     => "9",
            "top_zilla"       => "10",
            "top_division"    => "1",
            "top_description" => "Another Thing",
            "f_name"          => "Nazmul hossain",
            "l_name"          => "Apu"
        ), // end of tor_user_table [1]

        "skill" => array(
            "0" => array(
                "skill_id"    => "16",
                "top_user_id" => "9",
                "skill_name"  => "1"
            ),
            "1" => array(
                "skill_id"    => "18",
                "top_user_id" => "9",
                "skill_name"  => "2"
            )
        ) // end of skill table [1]
    ) // end of [1]
); // end of array
```

from one mysql query

> If there is a solution with temporary table , i want to know that too....................................
>    I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `tor_user_table` LEFT JOIN `skill` ON `tor_user_table`.`top_user_id` = `skill`.`top_user_id` WHERE `tor_user_table`.`top_full_name` LIKE $full_name_search_string AND `tor_user_table`.`type` = 1 AND `skill`.`skill_name` = 1 AND `tor_user_table`.`top_zilla` = 10
```

but It gives me only one skill that user have but I need all the skills that users have

Comment: I think he needs to use JOINS but I don't know what's the structure of the table and you should re-format that array output, it's messy. Do it and let us know

Comment: tor_user_table:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/07b4eqhwe4
skill:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0174eqi1ff


@JuanBonnett

Comment: Updated info ... @aberna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like following:

```
    SELECT * FROM skills as s Left join top_user_table as tot ON s.top_user_id = tot.top_user_id WHERE s.top_user_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
```

or,

```
    SELECT * FROM skills as s Left join top_user_table as tot ON s.top_user_id = tot.top_user_id WHERE s.top_user_id = 2
```

As per my understanding, you want to fetch all skills of a particular user with related info from top_user_table. So using above query you will get Array of objects in which every object will contain all related info of each of the skills.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know the output

```
SELECT * FROM `tor_user_table` LEFT JOIN `skill` ON `tor_user_table`.`top_user_id` = `skill`.`top_user_id` WHERE `tor_user_table`.`top_full_name` LIKE $full_name_search_string AND `tor_user_table`.`type` = 1 AND `tor_user_table`.`top_zilla` = 10
```

Comment: not as I expected :( .. here is the output http://pastebin.com/PvHF2J5K  i updated my post . please check that i already tried in this way , may be creating temporary table is the solution ? What do you think? :/ @JuanBonnett